# Recording video from webcam in MP4 format with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, video, webcam, mp4, web-mediarecorder

When I use the JS MediaRecorder to record webcam in MP4 format in a browser supporting MP4 and MediaRecorder (Firefox on Linux), the webcam starts but it does not record.

Recording has worked when the mimeType of the MediaRecorder is set to `video/webm` but when I set the mimeType to `video/mp4` the problem occurs.

I record with the following code:

```js
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
        var constraints = {audio: true, video: true};
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: "video/mp4"});
            mediaRecorder.start();
});
} else {
console.log("media recorder is not supported");
}
```

I expect the webcam to start recording when the code is executed in a supporting browser, but the `console.log` is not output and in the console there is the error of :

`NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported`

I know that my browser supports both mp4 and MediaRecorder:

MP4: https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4
MediaRecorder: https://caniuse.com/#search=mediarecorder

but only webm recording works.

Comment: Have you checked the result of `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported({mimeType: "video/mp4"})` to see if it's supported?

Comment: it is `false` What browser is mp4 supported in?

Comment: It's not specific to a browser, it can also be dependant on software installed on a machine. Or the processing capabilities of the device i.e. Multi-threaded CPU or Hardware Graphics encoding support. Try Chrome on Windows to see if it works. Also consider trying specifying encoding rates in the options too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that Chromium doesn't support mp4 recording either, so I decided to do the conversion on the server side after the video was uploaded.

Since it is GNU/Linux, to speed up the conversion I used:

`ffmpeg -i input.webm -preset superfast output.mp4`

If there are faster approaches I would like to know them.